# Tooltip with buttons and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a tooltip with buttons (Just like LinkedIn) for example.

This is what I have tried so far: (but stuck from here)

```css
.tooltip{
  display: inline;
  color:black;
  position: relative;
  top:200px;
}

.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -53px;
    width: 163px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before{
  border:solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0px 6px;
  bottom: 20px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>repl.it</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <a href="#" title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="tooltip"><span title="More">Linkedin Profile</span></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **Issue:**

1. But, I'm not able to figure out how to add `<buttons>` and also image to the tooltip?
2. How does the solution formulate for HTML/CSS/JS and HTML/CSS only?

> **Expected output:**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I suggest to use `popover`  instead of `tooltip` http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use Bootstrap `popover` as it is more flexible. See bootstrap documentation for popover [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/)

Here is a simple example on how to use it

## [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/J7nDz/1035/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Bootstrap 3 Popover HTML Example</h3>
    <span data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="left" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-default" >Click me</span>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
           <img width="88px" height="88px"src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/816404989392211968/Wv_8ZDrX_400x400.jpg"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8">
           <h4>
           Justin Trudeau <br/>
           <small>
             Prime minister of Canada
           </small>
           </h4>
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
           Follow
           </button>
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
           View profile
           </button>         
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html: true, 
        content: function() {
              return $('#popover-content').html();
            }
    });
```

Comment: Amazing Merlin! Just a thought, if i were to implement this natively, using standard HTML5/HTML4, CSS(/CSS3) how would i do that? (Just a thought)

Comment: You would need some javascript as well. Playing with div, showing/hiding element, determine the position on which element the popover should appears it should be ok to do it with HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT. But it is so easy to do it with bootstrap I wouldn't do it myself.